# Why can't print() be used in a lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

Why is:

```
p = lambda s: print(s)
```

invalid syntax but:

```
def do_print(s):
    print(s)
p = lambda s: do_print(s)
```

valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body of a lambda has to be an expression, not a statement. `print` is a statement.

Update: As pointed out, in 2.x, `print` is a statement while in Python 3, it is a function.

Comment: @sukhibr according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) `print()` is a function.

Answer (score 5):

which version of python are you using?; in python 2.7 (and before), print is a *statement* while in python 3 it's a *function*

Comment: in 2.7 you can do `from __future__ import print_function` to unify this

Comment: in python 2.6.6, `print` is a statement and as such can't occur in lambda expressions, the use of a wrapping function such as in your example is the recommended workaround

Answer (score -1):

its the way the language is read it can't do `p = lambda s: print(s)` all in one step